# Brake Mean Effective Pressure, how is this an effective measurement tool for engines?

Tags: engine, engine-theory

Many engine designers measure success with `Brake Mean Effective Pressure`

What are the equations used to calculate `Brake Mean Effective Pressure`?

Why is this a more or less effective measurement than other frameworks of measurement such as BSFC as illiterated in [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22121/fuel-consumption-at-same-speed-of-different-engine/22159#22159)?

How does understanding BMEP (Brake Mean Effective Pressure) drive engine design and solve performance problems that other equation tools cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of research has taught me that `Brake Mean Effective Pressure` is the ratio of an engines Torque to it's displacement, whereas the `Brake Specific Fuel Consumption` is the ratio of fuel consumption to the power produced.

In other words, `BMEP` will tell you how much power you can get from your engine at a given designed displacement, whereas `BSFC` will tell you how efficient that engine will be at a given power output. The two measurements are related but compete with each other.

In a design environment, especially with modern CAFE standards, I would start with the question of "What is my target fuel efficiency?". I would then ask myself "What is the minimum acceptable average power that my user expects in order to have a reasonable driving experience?". The answers to these question will give me a rough target for `BSFC`. Do note, though, that `BSFC` will change at different power output - I can design for a specific `BSFC` at a typical "standard" highway speed, or I can design for a `BSFC` at a typical 0-60 acceleration rate, or (more likely) try to do both.

Once I have my target `BSFC`, I can use that to help me design my engine. I'll use other factors (input from management, target demographic, etc) to determine whether I want a four-cylinder, v-6, v-8 etc. Then, I can play with various displacements and use the `BMEP` to figure out whether or not the theoretical engine will produce enough torque to meet my power requirements. I'll want to keep the `BMEP` high enough to produce enough torque so that the user's driving experience is not muted, but also low enough such that I do not miss the mark on my `BSFC` target.

I'd like to stress that this is a pretty simple overview, but hopefully it does give a bit of insight into how a typical design process may go.

Comment: It does give insight.  TY for the answer.